# Unable to install geth on my Azure Ubuntu 12.4

Tags: go-ethereum, installation, linux, ubuntu, microsoft-azure

Somehow, I am unable to install from this location:

```
bash <(curl -L https://install-geth.ethereum.org)
```

getting the error below:

```
error unable to install geth
```

screenshot:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Might be some permission issues, or the `ppa` is not updated. Try  `apt-get update ` and then install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.4 is not supported by the Ethereum repositories. [Only](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum-dev/ubuntu/dists):

- trusty/14.4
- utopic/14.10
- vivid/15.4
- wily/15.10

However, since you are on azure, you can install the [blockchain as a service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ethereum-blockchain-as-a-service-now-on-azure/) solutions which should also include a geth node.

Comment: thank you, yes finally  I had used azure blockchain as a service